# Nuxt js (vue js) Disabled default head links

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, nuxt.js

I'm creating a system and I'm using the vue-nuxt framework for the frontend of my application..
so far it´s a wonderfull js framework but I had a issue maybe someone can help me

this is my nuxt.config.js file

```js
export default {
  head: {
      titleTemplate: '%s',
      title: '..:: System Name ::..',
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en'
      },
      meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/logo.svg'}
      ]
    },
  plugins: ['~/plugins/axios',],
  components: true,
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/vuetify',],
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/auth'],
  auth: {
      redirect: {
        login: '/auth/login',
        home: '/',
        logout: '/auth/login'
      },
      strategies: {
        local: {
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: 'user/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
            user: { url: 'user/user-info', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
            logout: false,
          }
        }
      }
    },
  router: {middleware: ['auth']},
  axios: {baseURL: 'http://apisbackend.url.com'},
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/vars.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: "#558b2f",
          accent: "#cfd8dc",
          secondary: "#fff176",
          info: "#33b5e5",
          warning: "#ffbb33",
          error: "#ff4444",
          success: "#00C851"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  build: {
  }
}
```

How you can see I do not have any external url in my head configuration but when I render in develop mode the navegathor still tried to get external files like:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css

This appear inside my html->head code

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
     [...]
     <link data-n-head="ssr" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&amp;display=swap">
     <link data-n-head="ssr" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
     [...]
  </head>
  <body>
     [...]
  </body>
</html>
```

In the views or components develop by me I dont have any aditional external url configuration

I need some help to remove this external links from my system

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@nuxtjs/vuetify` automatically adds the [Roboto font](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/blob/96b1683/src/font.ts#L22) and [Material Design icons](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/blob/96b1683f4d5c738fb028ced8bf6cd0e067e984f6/src/icons.ts#L4) to `<head>`.

You can disable that by setting [`defaultAssets`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultAssets) to `false`:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  // Option 1: Build module options
  buildModules: [
     ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { defaultAssets: false }],
  ],

  // Option 2: top-level options
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/vuetify'],
  vuetify: { defaultAssets: false }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-remove-vuetify-default-cdn-links?file=nuxt.config.js)

However, you'll need to [manually setup the font/icons](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#offline-applications) yourself if you disable the default assets.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much it did not work but it gave me new ideas on how to solve it here I put the final solution that I found...
change this on my `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  vuetify: {
    defaultAssets: false,
    treeShake: true,
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, using top level options is an alternative config. However, the build module options should also work, as seen in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-remove-vuetify-default-cdn-links?file=nuxt.config.js). I've updated my answer.